# ASP.NET Core SignalR hub HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate returns null

Tags: signalr, x509certificate2, asp.net-core-signalr

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API with a SignalR hub.

My `Program.cs` has

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("MyScheme")
            .AddCertificate(opt => opt.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All)
            .AddCookie("MyScheme", options =>
            {
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Error";
                options.LoginPath = "/Home/Login/";
            });
builder.Services.AddSignalR();

builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(options =>
           {
               options.AddServerHeader = false;
               options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 8080, listenOptions =>
               {
                   listenOptions.UseHttps(certificate);
               });
           })
           .ConfigureKestrel(o =>
           {
               o.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(o =>
               o.ClientCertificateMode =
               ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate);
           })
           .UseIISIntegration()
           .UseUrls("https://*:8080");

app.MapHub<EPSHub>("/TESTHub", options => {
options.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets;});
```

My `web.config` looks like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    <security>
        <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert" />
        <authentication>
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
            <digestAuthentication enabled="false" />
            <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
            <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
        <requestFiltering>
            <!-- This will handle requests up to 1GB -->
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

My `TESTHub.cs` has a method `OnConnectedAsync` where I try to get the client certificate:

```
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    var httpCtx = Context.GetHttpContext();
    IHttpContextFeature feature = (IHttpContextFeature)this.Context.Features[typeof(IHttpContextFeature)];
    HttpContext cntx = feature.HttpContext;

    if (httpCtx.Connection.ClientCertificate is null)
    {
        var result = await httpCtx.Connection.GetClientCertificateAsync();
    }
}
```

But result always is null.

My client app is a WPF application using `AspNetCore.Client`.

`HubConnection.cs` has method:

```
private async Task StartConnection(string url)
{
    string certificate = @"C:\test\Certificate.pfx";
    var cert = new X509Certificate2(certificate, "1234", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

    Console.WriteLine("cert private key: " + cert.PrivateKey);

    var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                            .WithUrl($"{url}TESTHub", options =>
                            {
                                options.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
                            })
                            .Build();
    try
    {
        await hubConnection.StartAsync();

        if ((HubProvider.Connection is null ||
             HubProvider.Connection.State == HubConnectionState.Disconnected) &&
            hubConnection.State == HubConnectionState.Connected)
        {
            HubClientModel.ConnectAsync(hubConnection);
            _isConnectionExist = true;
            HubProvider.ServerURI = url;

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone dealt with this problem using SignalR in .NET 6 projects before?

I suggest my API need some additional configure for SignalR client certificates. But all my attempts for resolve this problem have not been successful

Comment: Have you put the `[Authorize]` attribute on your Hub class?

Comment: I have tried to use this attribute on method OnConnectedAsync - result was still null. But when I put this attribute to Hub class - I got  "Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)". Now I'm working for solve this exception.

Comment: I applied [Authorize] to Hub class, but Connection.GetClientCertificateAsync() returned null. I will be really appreciated if someone can help me.

Comment: [Does this article useful to you](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/azure-active-directorys-gateway-is-on-net-6-0/)?

Comment: @Jason Pan Azure it's not my case. I managed to solve my question. Client certificate was uncorrect. If someone have the same problem, I recommend to read this article - [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5315010/How-to-Use-Certificates-in-ASP-NET-Core)

Comment: Would you please explain how you managed to solve this? I read the article you mentioned and followed every step, still don't have any luck getting the certificate on server side. @Mxr_UA

Comment: @Mahsa You need to create a certificate by algorithm as described in article. After that put your certificate to Certification Authorities storage, set up your project. In my way, I had a problem with certificate and storage.